# How can I access the bash history with exact search, not prefix one?

Tags: bash, unix

I have two commands I execute frequently. Let's say the first is 'abcd' and the second is 'abc'. So my history contains

```
1000 abc arg1 arg2 arg3
1001 abcd arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Now if I type `!abcd` in bash, it executes the abcd command. which is fine. But if I type `!abc` in bash, it also executes the last abcd command (since it matches the beginning and is *"newer"*)

How do I use bash history to grab the last abc command? I've tried `!'abc '` and `"!abc\ "` backslashing the space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might try reverse history searching: Ctrl-R. On the prompt that appears, type in parts of your commandline (incremental text search).

If you want to switch to the previous match, type some more Ctrl-R.

In your "two similar lines" case,

```
Ctrl-R abc Ctrl-R
```

or

```
Ctrl-R abc<SPACE>
```

might do it

Answer (score 3):

Since Bash uses readline, try adding this to `~/.inputrc` and restarting Bash:

```
"\e[5~": history-search-backward
"\e[6~": history-search-forward
```

This lets you simply type

```
$ abc <PgUp>
```

to retrieve the last item in history beginning with `"abc "`.

There was a proposal to add these bindings to the default `/etc/inputrc` in some popular Linux distro... I don't remember what it was.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but if you execute those commands frequently, you might consider adding an alias or function definition to the appropriate login dotfile so that you can execute them with 1-letter commands:

```
alias a="abc arg1 arg2 arg3"
alias b="abcd arg1 arg2 arg3"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the history number, you could just

```
!1000
```

or use

```
!-2
```

refer to the line before previous.

Comment: I also thought about that. But it felt too static.

Who knows, maybe he has a readonly history file with his standard commands :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do what you're asking is to use the history search features in bash. With emacs keybindings (the default) you can press `CTRL-r`. With vi keybindings use `ESC /`. This will also let you search for other parts of the command.

Comment: You're right, didn't think of the different input methods (not speaking of customized bindings), ++ for that

Comment: I use vi bindings in bash, so I actually had to look up the emacs-bindings equivalent. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
!?abc ?
```

That's a space before the second question mark. Note that this (!?) would find "abc`<space>`" anywhere on the command line not just at the beginning as "!" would. The second question mark means that the string may have additional text after it (your args, for example) as well as delimiting the space character.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the dupes out of your history, put this in your bash startup (.bash_profile or .bashrc)

```
export HISTCONTROL="ignoredups"
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try https://github.com/dvorka/hstr which allows for "suggest box style" filtering of Bash history with (optional) metrics based ordering i.e. it is much more efficient and faster in both forward and backward directions:

[image]

It can be easily [bound](https://github.com/dvorka/hstr/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md) to <kbd>Ctrl-r</kbd> and/or <kbd>Ctrl-s</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Many good ideas here.  I'd like to add one more.  One thing I do to find frequently-used commands more easily via the bash history search (Ctrl-r) is to add a comment like #useful to the end so it becomes `echo I need this command or command sequence all the time #useful`.  Then I can cycle through those commands with <kbd>Ctrl-r</kbd>#use<kbd>Ctrl-r</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-r</kbd>...